# numpy - transform a list of objects into an array without subclassing ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For sake of simplicity I've defined a class that is not subclassed from `ndarray` (for many reasons I find it very complicated), but has an `__array__()` method that returns a nd.array of a given fixed shape. Let's call this class `Foo`.

In my script I also generate large lists of Foo instances, and I want to convert them into numpy arrays of arrays. I can easily do it using a map function:

> ```
> numpy.array(map(lambda x: numpy.array(x), [foo_1, ..., foo_n]))
> ```

and it works fine. I was just wondering how I can get things ever more simpler and efficient, and get the following to work:

> ```
> numpy.array([foo_1, ..., foo_n])
> ```

(actually it returns an "error return without exception set"...). It seems that providing an `__array__` method is not sufficient to authorize array conversion of lists. Any idea?

Comment: can you include a minimal definition of `Foo`? is `Foo` iterable?  Other than that, you should re-consider subclassing `ndarray`...

Comment: `Foo` is quite long. The key point is that is has a private attribute which is a 3x3 ndarray. I want Foo instances to behave like this private attribute in some cases, like the above one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [numpy.array docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), the object you pass in must satisfy:

> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

You're actually passing in a `list` of foo objects, so this list doesn't expose the array interface and doesn't have an `array` method.  That leaves only whether it's a nested sequence.  To be a nested sequence, your foo objects would likely need to be iterable.  Are they? ([emulating python's container types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types))

Not sure if this is any better, but you could probably do:

```
numpy.array([numpy.array(x) for x in [foo_1, ..., foo_n]])
```

Here is an example of `Foo`, as you've described.  It outputs the ndarray you'd expect (no exceptions).  Hopefully you can use it as an example:

```
import numpy as np

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]], np.int32)

    def __array__(self):
        return self.arr

    def __iter__(self):
        for elem in self.arr:
            yield elem

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.arr)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.arr[key]

def main():
    foos = [Foo() for i in range(10)]
    print np.array(foos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Tried to emulate iterable by defining the following methods to Foo: '__iter__', '__getitem__', '__len__','__contains__', '__add__', '__mul__','__rmul__', '__radd__', '__contains__' methods. They are simply copied from the private attribute which is a 3x3 ndarray. But this did not work either.

Comment: @Ssbd78: Not sure if your comment just got name-mangled or not, but did you try the underscore varieties?  eg.  _____iter_____

Comment: `@`Gerrat: fine! Did not work at first for me because I was too lazy and tried something like: `self.__array__ = self.arr.__array__` and so on (taking your example).

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit  more efficient and more concise, you don't need  the `lambda` with map:

```
numpy.array(map(numpy.array,[foo_1, ..., foo_n]))
```